# Calling UrlDecode in a C# .NET 4.0 Visual Studio 2010 Console Application?

Tags: .net-4.0, urldecode

OK, for some reason Microsoft removed System.Web but we can import System.Net.WebUtility and call HtmlDecode(), but how can we call UrlDecode()?

Please answer for .NET 4.0/VS2010 B2 ONLY.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about [Uri.UnescapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx)?

Comment: That works!  But why is something as well know as UrlDecode() getting a breaking change?

Comment: `System.Web` was only removed from the Client Profile.  If you switch to the full framework in project properties, it'll still be there.

Comment: I was running HttpUtility.UrlDecode in a service and it was throwing a ThreadAbortException. Switching to this function fixed the problem.

Comment: FWIW, the behavior is somewhat different, particularly with %uXXXX escape sequences.

Comment: @EricLaw Is there some other version of UrlDecode that accepts an encoding parameter but does not pull in System.Web?

Comment: @DarrelMiller: Not that I know of.

Comment: For more info, refer to [Rick Strahl's post on the same topic](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/617930.aspx).